# Routing between two AWS instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, routes

I have CentOS machine and microsoft server 2012
they are on the same AWS VPC and they share the same /24 subnet.
I want to configure an IP on the microsoft server and to reach it from the CentOS.
in order to do that I've configured the IP on the microsoft server and added a static route in the CentOS with the next hop of the internal IP of the microsoft, but no success so far.

can someone advise please?
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the internal IP addresses for communication within the VPC. You also need to make sure that the security groups the instances belong to allow communication between each other, over the necessary ports. You shouldn't need to mess with things like configuring static routes.

Comment: thanks for replying. the thing is that I want to add new IP to the microsoft server that will be reached via the CentOS: Internet --> CentOS --> Microsoft so I've configured the on the Microsoft and added a static route in the CentOS toward the Microsoft but it is not working :/